# Why do I need to define DLLImport with EntryPoint attribute

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

While going through [SWig](http://www.swig.org/) generated wrappers, I find that the PInvokes don't have any entry point defined, but some places do have an entry point. So what is the difference between them? When do I need to define an EntryPoint, and when do I not need to?

Defined without `EntryPoint`:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool ReadFile(
        HandleRef hndRef,
        StringBuilder buffer,
        int numberOfBytesToRead,
        out int numberOfBytesRead,
        int flag);
```

Defined with `Entrypoint`:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "ReadFile")]
public static extern bool ReadFile2(
        HandleRef hndRef,
        StringBuilder buffer,
        int numberOfBytesToRead,
        out int numberOfBytesRead,
        Overlapped2 flag);
```

Also why does the function have to be `static` as in `public static extern`? I assume that `extern` is telling the compiler that this method is defined externally?

Comment: In the example you posted you are importing the same method. This allows you to have two different implementations.  This is the reason code generators are basically useless if you don't understand the code they generate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`EntryPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.entrypoint.aspx) field serves to tell the .NET runtime which function to call from the DLL being invoked; if it's not set, the default is the same name that the .NET method declaration has. In your second example, omitting `EntryPoint = "ReadFile"` would result in the runtime trying to call a function named `ReadFile2` (which does not exist).

The prototype needs to have the `static` and [`extern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5.aspx) modifiers because the [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26thfadc.aspx) says so. It does not need to be `public`; controlling the visibility of the method is entirely up to you.